# Mono Compatible Networking/Socket Library

Tags: c#, networking, sockets, mono

Are there any Mono (C#) compatible networking / socket libraries out there?

Preferably something that is:

- Multi Threaded
- Event Driven
- Capable of multiple connections
- Handles client and server pieces
- Runs on Mono and MS .NET runtimes
- Very simple
- Free (And usable in commercial software)

It would also be really great if it was:

- .NET Compact Framework (Windows Mobile) compatible
- MonoTouch (iPhone) compatible

**Edit:**

To clarify more, what I meant by my "one level above TCP/IP" comment was that I want something that is basically a self contained server / client.  I don't want to have to deal with writing the threading code, handling each connection, etc.  For example, I would love for the code to look like this:

```
Server s = new Server(8080);
s.NewConnection += new ConnectionEventHandler(NewConnection);
s.DataRecieved += new DataEventHandler(NewData);
s.Start();

void NewConnection(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   s.Send((Connection)sender, "Hello World!"); //(Connection)sender is the connection instance so the server knows which to send the response to
}

void NewData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   s.Send((Connection)sender, e.Data); //Echo back
}
```

Not the cleanest code, but I think it gives the basic idea.

Comment: Do you mean IP sockets? I'd be suprised if anyone had bothered to write a full networking stack given it all there in System.Net & System.Net.Sockets. I guess there could be some wrapper libraries to add a specific enhancement I can't think of an example though.

Comment: Yes, I mean IP Sockets.  And sure, I can use the standard socket classes, but every time I do it's the same thing over and over.  I have to handle all the multi-threading / async stuff *again*
I just kind of figured that at this point that was basically done already.... I'm looking for something that is 1 level above TcpClient and TcpListener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this now exists, checkout [networkComms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net). Does all of the things you require and is also 100% compatible with mono.

*Disclaimer*: I am one of the developers for this commercial library.

Comment: This project went full commercial. Is there any new alternative?

Comment: @Sonny - If you are happy with the previous version then it is still available under GPL - http://www.networkcomms.net/download/gpl/

Comment: I can't get it working.

Comment: @Sonny - Please consider posting in the relevant support forums - http://www.networkcomms.net/forums/

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing out of the box that does what you want.

TcpClient/TcpListenr are already one level above Socket class. If you really want something that is even simpler, it is a very easy task to wrap TcpListener() and make it expose the event handler entry points that you want.

Comment: Strange... it just seems weird that this hasn't already been done.  Every time I do something that uses sockets I end up writing basically the same code over again... figured someone would've already done it and packaged it in a nice library.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [RemotingLite](https://www.codeplex.com/RemotingLite).  I use it with my Mono applications.  It was developed to aid in the networking aspect of the Distributed Computing Library [MPAPI](http://www.codeplex.com/MPAPI).  MPAPI had a goal of being 100% compatible with Mono.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear as to what exactly you expect from a class that is "one level above TcpClient and TcpListener"?

TcpClient/TcpListener are the basic building blocks you should use for development. I am not sure if they are supported in Mono as well, but if they are, then it should be all you need.

.Net CompactFramework also supports these, although I am not sure about Mono Touch.

Comment: By "one level above" I mean that I don't want to deal with writing the threading code, handling multiple connections, etc... see updated question above...