# Networking in Mono

Tags: mono, monodevelop

All,

I'm attempting to estimate the effort to port an app developed on Windows (.NET) to Linux (Mono).  I came across the MoMA tool, which attempts to look through my .exe and find potential areas of incompatibility.  Most of my issues appear to be centered around get/set of network settings, getting network info, etc. (Object ManagementBaseObject.get_Item and set_Item. etc).

In almost all of the cases, the Mono functionality is listed as "ToDo".  For estimation purposes, is it safe to assume most/all of these have some kind of workaround?  I would imagine this type of basic networking support must be included in the latest version of Mono.  Or should I assume none of this is currently available and I would be stuck waiting for it to be implemented (or be forced to implement it myself)?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Please note that the MoMA tool is severely outdated (it uses definitions from Mono 2.8) and might report results that aren't relevant on the current Mono 3.2.x anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First,see [Mono Compatible Networking/Socket Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408780/mono-compatible-networking-socket-library). Also,take a look on [Cross-Platform Network Applications with Mono](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7430). You can start with [C# Network Library](http://www.networkcomms.net/c-network-library/).